# Cannot set an element of one array equivalent to an element from a separate array using for looping and separate variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, numbers

I am new to JS, so I'm not 100% aware of all the different functions and methods associated with the program. I want to replace an element of one of my arrays with an element from another for a cheque writing program I am developing. Here is the code I have currently:

```
    loop = true
    units = ['zero ', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
    tens = ['', '', 'twenty ', 'thirty ', 'fourty ', 'fifty ', 'sixty ', 'seventy ', 'eighty ', 'ninety '];
    bigs = ['', 'hundred ', 'thousand ', 'million ', 'billion '];
    while (loop) {
        userNum = prompt("Enter your money quantity to 2 decimal places \neg: 123.45\n      100\n      3336745.90");
        if (userNum == parseInt(userNum) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(1) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)) {
            loop = false;
        } else {
            alert("That is not a valid number.");
        }
    }
    userNum = userNum.toString().split("");

    if (userNum.includes(".") == true) {
        a = userNum.indexOf(".");
        userNum[a] = "and";
    }

    for (i = 0; i > userNum.length; i++);
    if (Number.isInteger(userNum.lastIndexOf())) {
        num = userNum.indexOf(i);
        userNum.indexOf(i) = units.indexOf(num);
        console.log(userNum.indexOf(i));
    }
    alert(userNum);
```

I want to replace each element of "userNum" with their respective counterpart in "units" so my code will output each number as a word in the alert statement and to the console. E.g. 76.65 becomes seven,six,and,six,five. Currently, it just outputs the numbers and converts decimal points to ands, which leads me to believe the code just skips over the entire block of code. Is my syntax off, or am I going the wrong way about changing the elements? (Btw, I'm using VSCode, if that affects anything)

Comment: You forgot to mention what is the issue you are facing and . Also please add in the question the input and current output and also expected output.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the code:

1. userNum is already a string , no need to convert that to string.
2. Your for loop condition is wrong , it should be i less than nums.length  `i < userNum.length` 
   and there is semicolon (;) at the end of the for loop , which is wrong
3. lastIndexoOf() , methods needs the value to search for which is required parameter , syntax is

   `string.lastIndexOf(searchvalue, start)`
4. `userNum.indexOf(i) = units.indexOf(num);` . There is issue in this assignment here .
5. Also you dont need the units array till nineteen , zero - nine is fine .

Working solution with some modifications:

```js
var loop = true
var userNum ;

var units = {};

units[0]="zero";
units[1]="one";
units[2]="two";
units[3]="three";
units[4]="four";
units[5]="five";
units[6]="six";
units[7]="seven";
units[8]="eight";
units[9]="nine";
    while (loop) {
        userNum = prompt("Enter your money quantity to 2 decimal places \neg: 123.45\n      100\n      3336745.90");
        if (userNum == parseInt(userNum) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(1) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)) {
            loop = false;
        } else {
            alert("That is not a valid number.");
        }
    }
    userNum = userNum.split("");

    if (userNum.includes(".")) {
        a = userNum.indexOf(".");
        userNum[a] = "and";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < userNum.length; i++){
    if(userNum[i]!=='and'){
        userNum[i] = units[userNum[i]];
        console.log(userNum[i]);
       } 
    }
    alert(userNum);
```

Comment: This helps me out, but I have two questions: 1. What is the value that needs to be inputted into the searchvalue of the lastInxedOf method? I'm pretty sure that start is the index of the array to start at, but what about searchvalue?, and also 2. What is the issue with statement four? I can't really see it, so could you elaborate? Other than that, the other two were my mistakes. Thanks for pointing them out

Comment: 1. I dont really see the need to use lastIndexOf here . I am not sure why are you using it though. For understanding the usecase of lastIndexOf , please check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp  
2. It gives ```Invalid left-hand side in assignment``` issue . Because left hand side should be a variable  and not a constant and userNum.indexOf(i) , gives the value of the index or -1 .

Comment: I have added the working solution , please check that also .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to point out some mistakes in your code:-

1. You have a `;` after the for loop. You've to intend all the statement under `for` inside the curly braces except the `alert` method.
2. `indexOf` method returns the index of provided element inside the array. So, you don't need it.
3. Your `if` condition is wrong because all the elements inside the `userNum` array are already string so it will always return false.
4. Also it'll be `i < userNum.length` in the `for` loop.

I've edited the code. You can refer it from here :-

```js
loop = true
units = ['zero ', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ', 'ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ', 'nineteen '];
tens = ['', '', 'twenty ', 'thirty ', 'fourty ', 'fifty ', 'sixty ', 'seventy ', 'eighty ', 'ninety '];
bigs = ['', 'hundred ', 'thousand ', 'million ', 'billion '];
while (loop) {
    userNum = prompt("Enter your money quantity to 2 decimal places \neg: 123.45\n      100\n      3336745.90");
    if (userNum == parseInt(userNum) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(1) || userNum == (Math.floor(userNum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)) {
        loop = false;
    } else {
        alert("That is not a valid number.");
    }
}
userNum = userNum.toString().split("");

if (userNum.includes(".") == true) {
    a = userNum.indexOf(".");
    userNum[a] = "and";
}

for (i = 0; i < userNum.length; i++){
    if (userNum[i] !== "and") {
        num = parseInt(userNum[i]);
        userNum[i] = units[num];
    } 
}
alert(userNum);
```